# responsive website design is not working on mobile phone

Tags: html, responsive-design

responsive design is not working on my mobile phone but its working fine on my pc or laptop
i am working on this link  (http://abisyscorp.com/modelview)

```
    <head>
<link rel="stylesheet"   href="css/style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="max-width=480px">
<meta name="viewport" content="min-width=481px">
<meta name="viewport" content="min-width=1028px">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/detectmobilebrowser.js"></script>
<script src="js/tuchpunch.js"></script>
</head>
```

**Css**

css sheet link 
http://abisyscorp.com/modelview/css/style.css

```
@media tags in this site  

    @media screen and (max-width:480px){}
    @media screen and (min-width:481px){}
    @media screen and (min-width:1028px){}
```

Comment: Why does this question get an upvote? Can you post the CSS that causes the problem, not just link to your website that you will fix after getting an answer which makes the question useless to new readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your `<head>` section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=false;">
```

And remove:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="max-width=480px">
<meta name="viewport" content="min-width=481px">
<meta name="viewport" content="min-width=1028px">
```