# CSS responsive design in mobile is not working on uc browser and opera mini

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

Responsive website on UC and opera min browser not working properly(we used media query for responsive design). i searched around it i found some links:

[css responsive design in mobile is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273030/css-responsive-design-in-mobile-is-not-working)

[responsive website design is not working on mobile phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776920/responsive-website-design-is-not-working-on-mobile-phone)

but no success. Any help will be appreciated.... Thanks

**UPDATE**

We are viewing on google nexus-5.

website works properly on google chrome but not on UC and opera mini browser.

we are using below meta tag in our html

website is live please check on you mobile device(browsers: UC and Opera mini)

https://www.urbanbinge.com/#!/

Comment: Please post the code

Comment: Can you provide more details about what precisely is not working?

Comment: @j08691 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UC_Browser

Comment: is it an iphone you are trying to view it on? if so what is you min px width?

Comment: UC & Opera Mini use server-side rendering and have a smaller set of supported CSS features. Take a look at [this Opera blog post](https://dev.opera.com/articles/making-sites-work-opera-mini/) and a comparision of features of Opera Mini, UC Browser and Chrome: http://caniuse.com/#compare=chrome+43,op_mini+5.0-8.0,and_uc+9.9 You might be using an unsupported feature.

Comment: @Raj. Same problem with my website(https://www.winni.in/bangalore). It is not working fine with uc browser and opera mini in mobile. If you got solution then please share.

Comment: @Raj. I ask related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908037/i-want-to-see-console-of-mobile-browseruc-browser

Answer (score 8):

Opera mini and UC Browser have partial support for Javascript and it does not support 3d tranformation used for responsive menus e.g used by Foundation and Bootstrap frameworks (as these browsers are also not mentioned in their compatibilty list). Also they do not load gifs, you have to use svg images in place of that because both compress their assets before loading which make it much faster in compare to other browsers.

You can check below link for Opera Mini and UC Browser respectively:

https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-content-authoring-guidelines/

http://forum.ucweb.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=871055

You can fix that by detecting both browsers and fixing it by using HTML with jQuery Mobile.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: If you are sure then give me some idea for my website. Becuase same problem with me.https://www.winni.in/bangalore

Answer (score 2):

if babel is used with react preset of react-transform-remove-inline-elements then your javascript will not run in mobile UC browser. I found this issue when using react-starter-kit by Kriasoft.

Comment: Same problem with my website(winni.in/bangalore). It is not working fine with uc browser and opera mini in mobile. If you got solution then please share. Also ask related question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908037/i-want-to-see-console-of-mobile-browseruc-browser